# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'convert_objects'

Tags: machine-learning

My code-

```
data = data.replace("?", np.nan)
data = data.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

data.isnull().sum()
```

ERROR-

[image]

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1cfce90286bb> in <module>()
      2 
      3 data = data.replace("?", np.nan)
----> 4 data = data.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
      5 
      6 data.isnull().sum()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5139             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5140                 return self[name]
-> 5141             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5142 
   5143     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'convert_objects
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: It seems that [`convert_objects`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html) has been deprecated and replaced by [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html).

Answer (score 9):

The method `X.convert_objects()` seems to have been deprecated. I might be late to answer this, and the answer might not be entirely correct, but

```
X = X._convert(numeric=True)
```

might work for you. It did for me.

You could also check out `convert_dtypes()` but upon using this I ran into issues while performing operations like `mean()` (`Cannot perform reduction 'mean' with string dtype`).

Comment: Do you know why it was deprecated? :/